# ui:param value loses its value in included website (included by ui:include)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, jsf-2.3, java-ee-8

I have a JSF XHTML site which includes another JSF XHTML site (`example.xhtml`) via `ui:include`:

```xhtml
<p:dataTable> ...
  <ui:include src="example.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="sortByParam" value="MyValue"/> ...
```

Inside the `example.xhtml` site I use parameters like:

```xhtml
<ui:composition>
   <p:column sortBy="#{sortByParam}" ... />
```

This works at first glance flawless. But when I navigate forth and back between this and other sites the site breaks at some time - couldn't find a pattern so far. Because the attribute value of `sortBy` in `example.xhtml` gets actually passed to my bean as the string `#{sortByParam}` - not the value of the parameter (would be `MyValue` in this example).

At some point in time it stops evaluating the passed parameter and passes the attribute as it is directly to my Java code.

How do I stop that? Is this a bug?

I use Primefaces 7.0.3, Mojarra: 2.3.2, Java EE 8, Glassfish 5.0

Comment: You include "a website"??? And you include it IN a datatable? What do you actually in detail mean by that? And you navigate between websites??? You have to be more clear on what you mean by all this

Comment: @Kukeltje Edited, hope this is clearer.